# Use own arbitrary values ylim within Lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I would need lattice implementation of this example;

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(y=seq(0,1,0.1),x=rnorm(11,1,1))

# use different scale (y covariate) as used for plotting 
df$Num <- seq(0.5,1,0.05)

plot(df$x, yaxt="n")
axis(2, df$x[3], df$Num[3])
```

So how to display different figures as used for the graph.

or

```
df$L <- letters[1:nrow(df)]

plot(df$x, yaxt="n")
axis(2, df$x[3], df$L[3])
```

How to implement same thing in lattice `xyplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A translation of your first example would be

```
xyplot(x~seq_along(x), df, 
    scales=list(y=list(at=df$x[3], labels=df$Num[3])))
```

Read mode about the `scales=` parameter in the `?xyplot` help page.